# Install Linux on PPC Mac: NO CD DRIVE

Tags: linux, system-installation, macintosh

I am trying to install Linux on my Xserve G4, a NewWorld PPC Macintosh computer. The issue is: I have no CD drive, so all those helpful comments like "Just boot from Linux using a LiveCD" don't work for me.

I have disk images. I have a spare hard-drive that I can reformat until the blocks go bad.

1. Is it possible to boot from a Linux disk with the standard PPC OpenFirmware bootloader?
2. If not, how do I boot into Linux? All steps must be taken from the FreeBSD platform known as Mac OSX, or OpenFirmware

I asked a similar question on the AskDifferent forum, no more than 20 views and no replies, so I am coming here.

Thank you all.

Comment: Just boot via network

Comment: Why not try a usb?

Comment: Ashu, PPC Macs only support booting via USB indirectly, with some editing to the Open Firmware to make it possible.

Comment: @UlrichDangel, any advice on that? Google has turned up a blank...

Comment: @T.C. http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/powerpc/ch05s01.html.en for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have another machine on the network capable of running a tftp server, then you could try a network install.

this URL may help:

http://mac.linux.be/content/booting-open-firmware

it covers booting with open firmware from CD, hard disk, USB, and TFTP.

Comment: Ah, wonderful, it tells me how to get yaboot working on my root drive, regardless of OS... Now, how do I get those files? Every guide I have seen simply says "Those files you got from the Linux distribution" etc...
All 3 PPC Linux distributions I have only have yaboot, maybe ybin, and yaboot.conf, none of the other files...
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to boot to USB on XServe G4.  I was using the "memstick" bootable image I obtained from FreeBSD

ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/powerpc/powerpc/ISO-IMAGES/10.2/

I inserted my USB stick into the first usb port (in OF, it is known as "usb0")  Note, this has to be done directly for some reason; you can't insert the USB stick into a hub.  So, I have the USB stick inserted directly into the XServe and the mouse and keyboard in a hub.  By the way, I am using a plain ol' 1GB San Disk Cruzer.  You don't need anything fancy.

[image]

[image: XServe USB Port]

When I booted the XServe G4, I held down the the <kbd>Alt</kbd>key (I was using a PC keyboard, the Apple keyboard equivalent is <kbd>Option</kbd>)while the powering on, and the XServe started looking for all the possible boot devices.

After about a minute, it found the USB boot partition (as well as the other boot partitions installed).  [image: OpenFirmware Boot Screen].  The first drive is the FreeBSD Boot partition (I had already done the install using this method).  The 2nd is the FreeBSD USB Install, the third is the OS X partition that lives on the same drive as the first and finally, I have a drive with OS X install instead of using a CD-ROM.  (It was much faster this way)

Select the device and click the arrow; in this case, select the USB drive.  You will then see the boot messages:
[image: OpenFirmware USB Boot]

After about a minute or two, you should be able to proceede with your install:

[image: FreeBSD USB Install]

Answer (score -1):

You can mount a CD (not using any tray) using Daemon tools, or something similar, and then mount it a Drive (e.g. E:/). Then just reboot your Linux machine, and it should boot up with the CD image.

Comment: Don't have a Linux machine, only OSX.